# Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, automated-tests

I tried to run default test in react-native using jest and I found this problem:

```
Test suite failed to run

Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument.

  at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
  at new NativeEventEmitter (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:44:7)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-clipboard/clipboard/dist/NativeClipboard.js:15:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-native-clipboard/clipboard/dist/Clipboard.js:24:38)
```

I completly dont know how to solve this problem.

Ive tried to add the following line:

> jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter');

to jest.setup.js

or

> **mocks**/native_event_emmiter.js

but neither solution works.

Anyone know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you add `setupFiles` in your `jest.config.js`?

This worked for me:

```
//jest.config.js

setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
```

```
//jest.setup.js

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter');
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer/issues/367#issuecomment-953662440

Answer (score 3):

these two lines in 'jest.setup.js' fixed the issue:

```
import mockRNDeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info/jest/react-native-device-info-mock"
jest.mock("react-native-device-info", () => mockRNDeviceInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have added a package in package.json and forget to add the config
in ios podfile you can either remove the package from package.json or add the config for ios that helped me. The run npm i

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to mock `react-native-fs` in unit test case to solve this dependency issue.

```
jest.mock('react-native-fs', () => {
 return {
  mkdir: jest.fn(),
  moveFile: jest.fn(),
  copyFile: jest.fn(),
  pathForBundle: jest.fn(),
  pathForGroup: jest.fn(),
  getFSInfo: jest.fn(),
  getAllExternalFilesDirs: jest.fn(),
  unlink: jest.fn(),
  exists: jest.fn(),
  stopDownload: jest.fn(),
  resumeDownload: jest.fn(),
  isResumable: jest.fn(),
  stopUpload: jest.fn(),
  completeHandlerIOS: jest.fn(),
  readDir: jest.fn(),
  readDirAssets: jest.fn(),
  existsAssets: jest.fn(),
  readdir: jest.fn(),
  setReadable: jest.fn(),
  stat: jest.fn(),
  readFile: jest.fn(),
  read: jest.fn(),
  readFileAssets: jest.fn(),
  hash: jest.fn(),
  copyFileAssets: jest.fn(),
  copyFileAssetsIOS: jest.fn(),
  copyAssetsVideoIOS: jest.fn(),
  writeFile: jest.fn(),
  appendFile: jest.fn(),
  write: jest.fn(),
  downloadFile: jest.fn(),
  uploadFiles: jest.fn(),
  touch: jest.fn(),
  MainBundlePath: jest.fn(),
  CachesDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  DocumentDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  ExternalDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  ExternalStorageDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  TemporaryDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  LibraryDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  PicturesDirectoryPath: jest.fn()
 }
})
```